# Go build ignores files without saying anything

Tags: windows, go, build

I'm getting some really strange behavior when attempting to build a windows version of my go program.

My directory contains:

```
foo.go  
foo_windows.go  
foo_windows_test.go  
foo_unix.go  
foo_linux.go  
foo_linux_test.go  
foo_darwin.go
```

Windows builds are failing because the build ignores foo_windows.go, for some reason. Note, there are no `// +build` comments in any files. Here's the output of the build file list:

```
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go list -f '{{.IgnoredGoFiles}}' github.com/foo/
[foo_darwin.go foo_windows.go foo_windows_test.go]

$ GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go list -f '{{.IgnoredGoFiles}}' github.com/foo/
[foo_linux.go foo_linux_test.go foo_windows.go foo_windows_test.go]

$ GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go list -f '{{.IgnoredGoFiles}}' github.com/foo/
[foo_darwin.go foo_linux.go foo_linux_test.go foo_unix.go foo_windows.go]
```

Obviously the last item is very wrong. foo_windows.go should not be ignored. Note that when including the methods in `foo_windows.go` in `foo.go` directly, the windows build succeeds, so it really is excluding the file, and the file contains everything needed for a good build.

Both cross-compiling on a mac and compiling normally on a windows machine lead to the same problems of file exclusion, which leads me to believe it's something about the file itself that is causing problems, but I'm not sure what it might be.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can't reproduce on any Go version from 1.2 to 1.5.1. Are you sure it's not a misprint? Have you tried adding an explicit build tag?

Comment: Yes, adding `// +build windows` in the `foo_windows.go` file doesn't change anything. FWIW, I've been using Go version 1.5.1. Also, I doubt it's a misprint, since putting the code from `foo_windows.go` into `foo.go` makes the build successful. It appears that it might be something in the `foo_window.go` file, but besides `// +build` comments, I'm not sure what effects a build.

Comment: A wild guess: You have strange characters in the filename "foo_windows.go". Maybe the name just _looks_ like foo_windows.go but there is a invisible space or the w is a capital one or the i is a cyrillic/turkish/whatever one?

Comment: @Volker Good suggestion. I recreated the file entirely to make sure the name was all normal text and it changed nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question and hope it helps someone else.

`foo_windows.go` was not included in the build because of unexpressed build errors. Specifically, `foo_windows.go` contains C code, and because `CGO_ENABLED=0` by default, go didn't try compiling it, it just saw there was C code in the file and excluded the file. Setting `CGO_ENABLED=1` included the file in the build.